# supersingular Abelian scheme

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, abelian-varieties, shimura-varieties, abelian-schemes

By a *supersingular Abelian scheme*, I mean an Abelian scheme which is fibrewise a supersingular Abelian variety, i.e. isogenous to a product of supersingular elliptic curves (F. Oort, *Subvarieties of moduli spaces*. Invent. Math. **24** (1974), 95–119).

Let $\mathscr{A}$ be a supersingular Abelian scheme over an *integral* variety over $\mathbf{F}_p$. Is it true that $\mathscr{A}$ is isogenous to a product of relative elliptic curves over $X$? I am looking for a reference. Equations (0.4.1), (0.4.2) in [Li-Oort, *Moduli of Supersingular Abelian Varieties*, LNM 1680] seem to imply this.

Comment: You want this to be true without a base change of your integral variety $S$?  For a finite subgroup $\Gamma$ of $\textbf{GL}_n(\mathbf{Z})$ and for a $\Gamma$-torsor $S'\to S$, for every elliptic curve $E$ over $\mathbf{F}_p$, for the Abelian variety $A=E^n = E\times_{\text{Spec}(\mathbf{F}_p)}\dots \times_{\text{Spec}(\mathbf{F}_p)} E$ with its natural action of $\textbf{GL}_n(\mathbf{Z})$, there is an Abelian scheme over $S$, $\mathcal{A} = (S' \times_{\text{Spec}(\mathbf{F}_p)} A)/\Gamma$.  Do you expect $\mathcal{A}$ to be isogenous to a product over $S$?

Comment: @Jason Starr: I think a finite étale base change would be OK.

Comment: You can also assume $\mathscr{A}$ to be principally polarised.

Comment: Here's a naive remark which I hope might be useful. Let $x$ be an $\mathbb F_p$-point of the base $S$ (assuming it exists) and let $E$ be the fibre of $\mathcal A$ over $x$. Then, do you expect $\mathcal A$ to be isogenous to $E^g\times S$, up to finite etale base change? If so, then you could try to show that the scheme of isogenies $Isog_S(\mathcal A, E^g\times S)$ is finite etale over $S$. It is at least surjective by the results in Li-Oort...(You might want to consider a subscheme parametrizing isogenies of some bounded degree, and maybe also of degree coprime to $p$.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $K = K(X)$ be the function field of $X$.  By Frans Oort, *Subvarieties of moduli spaces*. In: Invent. Math., 24 (1974), 95–119., p. 113, Theorem 4.2, $\mathscr{A}_{\bar{K}}$ is isogenous to $E_{\bar{K}}^g$ with $E_{\bar{K}}/\bar{K}$ any (!) supersingular elliptic curve (any two supersingular elliptic curves over an algebraically closed field are isogenous, see *loc. cit.*, p. 113).  Note that for any prime $p$, there exists a supersingular elliptic curve over $\mathbf{F}_p$, see Silverman, *The Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves*, p. 148f., Theorem V.4.1(c) for $p > 2$ and the text before this theorem for $p = 2$.  By Milne, http://jmilne.org/math/articles/1986b.pdf, p. 146, Corollary 20.4(b) applied to the primary field extension $\bar{K}/K^{\mathrm{sep}}$, there is a separable field extension $L/K$ and an isogeny $E_L^g \to \mathscr{A}_L$.  Since $E/\mathbf{F}_p$ extends to $E \times_{\mathbf{F}_p} X$ over $X$, the claim follows from [extending homomorphisms of Abelian schemes](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/265505/extending-homomorphisms-of-abelian-schemes).